# Cluster Expansion vs Cluster Decomposition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics

Are the cluster expansion (which we encounter in Statistical Physics), and cluster decomposition (in Quantum Field Theory) related to each other?

(I have a reason to believe they are)

Answer (score 2):

This [*stat-phys thing* (cluster expansion)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_expansion) and that [*qft thing* (cluster decomposition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_decomposition_theorem) are related by both referring to the notion of [cluster, being "*a small group or bunch of something.*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster);

- the former referring rather to cluster in the sense of a "*group*" of some particular (small, or large) **number** of members,
  with particular and primary attention given to **pairwise** membership (thus not including clusters in the degenerate sense of having only one member),
- the latter referring rather to cluster in the sense of a "*bunch*" of members that are **coincident**,
  thereby characterizing pairs of members of distinct bunches as **not** coincident (and including the notion of a bunch in the degenerate sense of having only one member).

(More might be said, 'cause that's really my kinda bag ...)

Comment: I swear -I typed expansion instead of decomposition by accident.

Comment: Just corrected the question, about to elaborate on the question  as soon as I get on my pc.

Comment: kevin Tah N: "_I swear -I typed expansion instead of decomposition by accident._" -- Presumably that refers to "_expansion_" in the phrase "_some Weinberg bablings about cluster expansion_" in the original question statement, which by now has been edited. I, in turn, admit I had read more of Weinberg's QTofF, vol. 1, §4.3 than of the [Wikipedia page on cluster decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_decomposition_theorem) before submitting my answer. (I put the link there anyways; HTH.) "_about to elaborate on the question as soon as [...]_" -- You're not helping! (Me, anyways. ;)

Comment: awesome, I remember the last time I read about this was told it could help with qcd eventually. Can you possibly provide some guide to how this, facilitates the understanding of quark properties.