# Cluster Expansion and Partition Function for a Collection of Interacting Particles in Presence of an External Potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics, interactions, partition-function

I was watching a lecture on statistical mechanics (link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bHAUZgXavI)) in which the instructor explains the statistical mechanics of weakly interacting gas molecules (no external potential) using the standard cluster expansion of in terms of *Mayer f function*. He then very briefly explains that if we assume that an external potential exists we will be dealing with two kinds of nodes in the cluster diagrams. He states that these nodes can be represented by usual black circles which are the integration variables and the white circles which we can't integrate anymore. He then gives a couple of references in physics of liquids and proceeds the lecture without assuming the external potential.

I checked the sources by the explanations were too cumbersome and lengthy for me to understand. I was curious how can I get to the mentioned description using simple and standard mathematical steps that we take while deriving the regular cluster expansion. Assume that the inter-particle potential is denoted by $U(r_{ij})$ and the external potential is denoted by $W(r_n)$. The partition function is:

$Z(N,V,T)=\frac{1}{N!h^{3N}}[\int \prod_{i} d^3p_i e^{-\beta\sum_j \frac{p_j^2}{2m}}][\int \prod_{i} d^3r_i e^{-\beta\sum_{j<k} U(r_{jk})-\beta\sum_n W(r_n)}]$

Defining the Mayer function $f(r)=e^{-\beta U(r)}-1$ and using the notation $f_{ij}=f(r_{ij})$, after integrating over the momentum degrees of freedom we can write:

$Z(N,V,T)=\frac{V^N}{N!h^{3N}}[\int \prod_{i} d^3r_i \prod_{j<k} (1+f_{jk}) e^{-\beta\sum_n W(r_n)}]$

By expanding the product we can write:

$Z(N,V,T)=\frac{V^N}{N!h^{3N}}[\int \prod_{i} d^3r_i (1+\sum_{j<k}f_{jk}+\sum_{j<k,l<m}f_{jk}f_{lm}+...) e^{-\beta\sum_n W(r_n)}]$

If we ignore the exponential term containing $W(r)$ (external field), we easily get the standard cluster expansion using the diagrammatic approach. What I don't understand is what should we do with the $e^{-\beta\sum_n W(r_n)}$ term in order to get to the description that was explained in the first paragraph.